# Postfix not working with user@example.com type user

Tags: postfix, virtualhost

I have some virtualhost set up on Centos 7.1, I want to have user like `user@example.com` so that I can reply via `user@example.com` and not like `user@localhost.localdomain`

Postfix is working with user like `user` but not with `user@example.com`, It shows error `status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)`;

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd   $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 62.210.xx.xx/24, 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relay_domains =
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = example1.com example2.com example3.com 
virtual_alias_maps = dbm:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual**

```
example1.com example1.com
#admin@example1.com admin
admin@example1.com admin@example1.com
```

When I do this it works I recieve mail

```
example1.com example1.com
admin@example1.com admin
```

I get error `status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table) doing this`

```
example1.com example1.com
admin@example1.com admin@example1.com
```

Please suggest any possible way to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating sender canonical map

```
/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
user   user@example.com
```

Then mapping

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

Then adding it to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

Now Restart Postfix

Now I can send mail from `user` as `user@example.com`

Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a relay_recipients map:

/etc/postfix/relay_recipients:

```
user1@example.com   ok
user2@example.com   ok
```

Of course you would map it with:

```
$ postmap relay_recipients
```

Then move the map to your postfix directory and restart your service:

```
$ sudo mv relay_recipients.db /etc/postfix/
$ sudo service postfix restart
```

Exerts from /etc/postfix/main.cf:
/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 12.34.56.0/24
relay_domains = example.com
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination

relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

For your virtual aliases perform the same type of postmap.

Create the virtual alias file `virtual`:

```
/user@.*/          user@example.com
user@example.com   user
```

Execute:

```
$ postmap virtual
$ sudo mv virtual.db /etc/postfix/
$ sudo service postfix restart
```

Comment: how do I mention this relay map in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Comment: @TallboY `relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients`

Comment: I did as you said but still get this error `status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)`

Comment: Please add your virtual alias file to your question (`/etc/postfix/virtual_alias`)... I'm testing and will also add an example virtual alias file to my answer.

Comment: With `/user@.*/ user@example.com` Now I am getting error `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table`

Comment: @TallboY Look at the updated answer block of the virtual alias file.  Also, please add the related lines from your virtual alias file to your question.

Comment: `postmap: fatal: open virtual: No such file or directory` `mv: cannot stat ‘virtual.db’: No such file or directory` this works however `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`

Comment: @TallboY Copy the text file /etc/postfix/virtual to a work directory.  Execute the postmap commands from the work directory.

Comment: What work directory?

Comment: @TallboY `mkdir ~/postfixwork` then `cd ~/postfixwork`... You can call the work directory anything.

Comment: How will I then assign this directory to postfix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32442/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-tall-boy).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you mix up two differently purposed Mail Delivery Agents (MDAs). Long story short, postfix comes with two MDA - local and virtual. main.cf parameters like mydomain, local_recipient_maps etc. are used by local and thus not applicable for virtual. So, as it was mentioned above you need to create another user maps for virtual MDA. (virtual_mailbox_maps)

In the mos basix form, the purpose of those MTAs is that local is bound to system user accounts (like /etc/passwd) shared between all domains, while the virtual can serve different users and domains. For any further info on this you should refer to postfix documentation, it's pretty descriptive and easy to understand.

BTW If you want postfix to serve user mail, consider using SASL (SMTP authentication).